# How can I conditionally build a project in my solution only on TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, artifactory

I'm using the JFrog plugin to Visual Studio 2013 with TFS 2015. This plugin is a template for publishing NuGet packages on TFS builds. Automated vNext Builds on TFS work very well with Artifactory and publish my NuGet packages to our Artifactory instance. When I build locally, I do not want the Artifactory project to build, because I do not want to publish every time I build in Visual Studio. Is there a way to make sure the solution doesn't build the project locally, but does build when the solution is used in TFS builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a solution configuration with the Artifactory project uncheck and use this configuration to build locally. And in TFS build use the configuration with the Artifactory project checked to build the solution. Refer to this link for details: [How to: Exclude Projects from a Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676765.aspx)